# Facebook share button gives blank popup for website homepage

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I've created a Facebook share button using the auto generated code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

I'm trying to make it share pages from a WordPress page I'm working on. For some reason, when I try to share the website's homepage, I just get a blank popup box and nothing loads. If I try to share any page from the site other than the homepage the popup works and I can share the page. I've also checked the home page in the Facebook debugger and it scrapes all of the data from the page fine.

I'm thinking that it might be some issue with the way WordPress handles the url of static front pages but I can't be sure. Any insight on this issue would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon later inspection and chance circumstances, I found an extremely easy solution to this problem. In the code for the share button I used:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://mywebsite.org/index.php" data-type="button">
```

Changing the data-href link to my website's homepage to include "/index.php" did the trick. I had tried webpage.com/index but not index.php but it is working now. If anyone has the same problem I would suggest trying that.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand you much but i am assuming that when you try to share your home page in Facebook then it is showing only blank box.

If this is the problem then it might be possible that you do not have a meta description and title for your homepage.

- Using this you can set the image that will be shown in the Facebook. Beside this for Title:

and use this tools https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Hope this help.

Edit:

`<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-type="button_count"></div>`

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. When I try to share the home page, I get a blank page where the share prompt should come up. I've added the necessary meta tags and that didn't help. I also mentioned that I used the Facebook debug tool in the original post. I apologize if that was unclear.

Comment: can you provide me the URL.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmedicarerightsuniversity.org%2F

As I also mentioned, other pages on the website work with the share button I'm trying to implement but the homepage does not.

I can't provide you a link to where I am trying to make the share button work because it is on a development site, but you can paste any urls into https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/ to get the same buttons I'm trying to use.

Comment: see the edit above, hope changing data-href urls in your button code to the perma link will help.

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Then without seeing your page it's not possible to say.